# ASP Net Core SignInManager not signing in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a simple web api project built on .Net Core 3.1 with EF Core as well.
I have tried to follow DDD pattern, and my app is structured in the following way (separate projects):

- Web Api
- Models
- Services
- EF (entity framework)
- Tests
- EF Migrator (console app that I will speak later in this question)

My ApplicationDbContext stored under `EF Project` uses `DefaultIdentity` where my CofigureServices under `Web Api Project` look like following (this is an intranet application, thus confirmed account is not required):

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
 services.AddDefaultIdentity<UserDB>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
         .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then when I try to log in application (via LoginController) I have created the following simple method:

```
[HttpGet("signin")]
[MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
public async Task<bool> SignIn([FromQuery]string username, [FromQuery] string password)
{
    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, false, false);
    return result.Succeeded;
}
```

When I create an account from my Web Api application, everything works great, just as expected. However in my case, as on the target server (where this application will be deployed) I do not have access to install custom tools (such as EF Core tools), therefore in order to do the migrations on the target server (and also to control initial seed) I have decided to create a separate Console app `EF Migrator Project` (within the same solution and that has dependecies on my ef core as well) which looks like this:

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", true, true)
.Build();

```
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services, config);
        serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        context.Database.Migrate();
        await SeedRoles(context, serviceProvider);
        await SeedUsers(context, serviceProvider);
    }



private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();


        // Register UserManager & RoleManager
        services.AddIdentityCore<UserDB>()
           .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


        // UserManager & RoleManager require logging and HttpContext dependencies
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }
```

Then I create a user in a database like following (simplified):

```
 static async Task SeedUsers(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (await context.Users.AnyAsync())
                return;

            var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<UserDB>>();
            var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(new UserDB() { Id = "fakeuser", ... }, "fakepassword");

            var userAddedResult = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(result);
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userAddedResult , "ADMIN");
        }
```

Now when I open SQL server I can clearly see that my user has been created and stored in the database. However, when I switch back to my ASP.NET application and try to sign in (with same credentials) it now forbids me and looks like it does not recognize me (result from Sign-In is false).

Is there anything that I missed in my setup? To me this seems like my console app has created a new user from it's own context (maybe using custom hash algorithm) which is not recognized by my ASP.NET side?

Comment: When you run from VS you are not running as an Admin unless you right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: The problem is not running as admin, but that my WebApi does not want to sign in user that was created with console app - EF Migrator

Comment: Can you signin with SQL Server Management Studio.with username and password.  First get the credentials working with SSMS.  SSMS login window usually shows Windows Credentials and will default to the user login.  Then make sure you can do a query of the database from SSMS.  Once SSMS works than go back to c#.  This is not a c# issue.  The database credentials has to allow a username and password.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem was with my `EF Migrator` setup. I was adding a new user in the following way:

```
var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(new UserDB() { Id = adminEmail, Name = "Admin", **UserName = "Admin"**, NormalizedUserName = "Admin", Email = adminEmail }, adminPassword);
```

and I was not aware that signin is done through username. Once I changed `UserName` to actual email (through which I was doing the log-in), it worked like a charm. This is how it should look like:

```
var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(new UserDB() { Id = adminEmail, Name = "Admin", **UserName = adminEmail**, NormalizedUserName = "Admin", Email = adminEmail }, adminPassword);
```

Furthermore I have slightly updated my setup code so it's now in sync what I have in actual `WebAPI` project:

```
 private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();


            // Register UserManager & RoleManager
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<UserDB>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
               .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                ... other setup
            });

            // UserManager & RoleManager require logging and HttpContext dependencies
            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        }
```